# Why Boltzmann Entropy's formula is $k_B\log\ W$ and not $0.5\ k_B\log\ W$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

This question is probably wrong - however, I wish to understand even *why* it's wrong..

Let's take the monatomic gas situation. By the Equipartition theorem, we have that for every degree of freedom the mean energy is $0.5\ k_BT$. So, why in the definition of the Boltzmann Entropy we have $k_B\log\ W$ and not $0.5\ k_B\log\ W$?

Comment: Why would you expect the 1/2 in the equipartition theorem to have anything to do with the entropy?

Comment: It's just a definition. You can put the $1/2$ in there, but you'll get factors of $2$ everywhere in the formulas.

Comment: @DanielSank, very roughly my idea was that entropy is linked to the number of degrees of freedom of a system

Comment: At first I thought this was a bit of a misguided question, but it is actually quite interesting. Let me attempt to rephrase it: if we have a system at temperature T, and we suddenly activate a new degree of freedom whilst keeping T constant, then $\Delta E = T \Delta S$. If the equipartition theorem applies, we then derive that the volume of phase corresponding to a degree of freedom is $\sqrt{e}$. The question is then: why? Or, is there a mistake in this reasoning? Indeed, I would be inclined to distrust this reasoning, because such factors should be ambiguous, but I can't see the flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I see with the idea is that it seems contradictory. You used the definition of entropy of the microcanonical ensemble, which is defined by assigning an equal probability to every microstate whose energy falls within a range centered at E. All other microstates are given a probability of zero. That is,  the range of energy is reduced in width until it is infinitesimally narrow, still centered at E( In the limit of this process, the microcanonical ensemble is obtained).
The equipartition theorem , on the other hand, allows a range of energies of which $\frac{1}{2}kT$ is the average. It is not surprising then that the mixing of the two formalisms result in
 (I would not say contradictory) non consistent results.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks! It becomes even more evident thinking of the *generalized* equipartition theorem..!

Answer (score 0):

Assume we already know the relation $S\propto\log{W}$. Then we can define a coefficient of proportionality as $k_\text{B}$ and write $S=k_\text{B}\log{W}$. So it is defined including all possible multiplication ambiguities from the beginning. Basically, this is a same question asking why we should choose $m$ not $2m$ or something else in Newton's second law, $F=ma$.